# Deserialize JSON using annotated property names and serialize using original property names (ignoring annotations)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I receive JSON from an external service, and said JSON can have field names that don't work well with C# naming rules. Such as

```
"$" : {//object definition here}
```

I can't name my classes as a single '$'. I'm using System.Runtime.Serialization data annotations to specify a field from which to deserialize this weirdly named object:

```
 [DataMember(Name = "$")]
 public Item Info { get; set; }
```

Deserialization works, but now I would like to format this a bit better so that it wouldn't get serialized back to to `"$" : {//object definition here}` again. Is there a way I could specify a serialization rule that says that this field needs to be serialized with property name `Info` while still being deserialized from a member named `$`? What I would like the user of my service to see is this:

```
"Info" : {//object definition here}
```

Comment: Can you use JSON.NET? You can write your own converter in there that allows you to specify how it's read and written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a custom `IContractResolver` that basically tells Json.Net to ignore your property name annotations.  On deserialization, you let Json.Net work as normal, so the annotations are used.  On serialization, you add the resolver to the serializer settings, which causes Json.Net to use your class property names instead of the annotated names.

Here is the code you would need for the resolver:

```
class OriginalNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        // Get the JsonProperties (with annotated names) from the base class
        IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        // For each property, replace the annotated name with the real name
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in list)
        {
            prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is a demo showing how it works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""$"" : { ""$moniker"" : ""blob sprocket"" } }";

        Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("name from JSON = " + foo.Info.Name);
        Console.WriteLine();

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new OriginalNameContractResolver();
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("$")]
    public Item Info { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("$moniker")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
name from JSON = blob sprocket

{
  "Info": {
    "Name": "blob sprocket"
  }
}
```